# Is it possible to make ebooks readable on the browser but restrict it from getting downloaded by the user?

Tags: javascript, web

I want to certain ebooks to be accessible on my website for the users but I don't want them to be able to download it.

They should be just able to read it online. Is it possible?

> Editing the question based on Alex's answer.
>
> It seems like everything you see is downloaded so there is not way to restrict it.
>
> But can I make it really difficult for the user?

Few options that I can think of are:

1) I read somewhere that I can convert my book to swf format and show it in an swf player which will restrict the download of the file. Is that an option?

2) Another option that I can think of is restricting right click/ control options on the page. I am not sure how good an option it is?

Answer (score 0):

You can never see anything on your computer that you haven't downloaded to it.

So no, you cant.  Attempting to would be an exercise in futility.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this bot only to a certain extent. Practically you encrypt your files and you load a non javascript extension that will decrypt the files when showing them(flash or unity would have been great but are now unsupported). This will keep them safe.

However, at some point someone could take that .flv file or whatever you used and decompile it and  extract the code which decrypts your files. How ever you can make that pretty complicated if you really want safety.